# SignalR Symmetric Encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography, signalr

I need to implement a basic SignalR chat example, but with symmetric encryption to

1. Prevent others in the chat without the proper passphrase from reading what they shouldn't be allowed to
2. Prevent snooping over a network

The passphrase would be agreed upon outside the bounds of the program, exchanged physically, and therefore passphrase exchange is not part of the problem.

To accomplish this, I have the basic SignalR Getting Started project

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

and I added a Crypto class with an encrypt(message, key) method and decrypt(message, key) method.

The idea would be to have the message be encrypted, sent to everybody, then decrypted by everyone. I can send the encrypted message by just using the default Chat Send method and encrypting the message before sending, but I am not sure of how to call the decrypt method once the message is received.

Basically I want to receive the message and then before appending it to the DOM, call a C# method (the decrypt method), get back the correct string, and then proceed with it.

Is this possible with SignalR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the message to travel unencrypted then no,it can't be encrypted and decrypted in c#. You need to do that within the context of your browser's context, thus limiting you to basically javascript. 
Anyway, if you host the app in an https site, nobody should be able to sniff anything.